For the fourth time, I don’t know what to buy!
This is the sequel to this puzzle.

My cryptic and rude roommate asked me to get something AGAIN!!!
“What am I supposed to buy?” I grumble.
“Buy it or I’ll crush your toilet cubicle!” He replies.
“What nonsense is he saying? How is he able to crush a toilet cubicle?” I mutter to myself.
What am I supposed to buy?

Very Minor Hint:

 It’s a food as usual.

Hint:

 My roommate came up to me and said this: “Why did I say crushed toilet cubicles! I should’ve said crushed living quarters!”


You want to buy...

 MUSHROOMS

Since...

 Crush = MUSH

 Toilet cubicle (or living quarters, in the hint) = ROOM(s)


Well done! Correct!

When you crush something you turn it into

 MUSH,

And a toilet cubicle, or water closet, is a

 ROOM,

So your friend wants you to get

 MUSHROOMS


Already posted this one myself, I'm afraid...

Correct as well, but they did post it earlier so I’m just giving you an upvote.

@Stiv dangit, should have refreshed

Maybe buy a

 THUMBSTALL, which sounds like a toilet cubicle crushed to the size of a thumb!


Sadly incorrect.

Could it be

SALT?

Which is a crushed

STALL

And also a foodstuff. Technically.

Sadly incorrect. I think I need to add another hint.
